# How to group rows in mysql to be as chunks with a specific size

Tags: mysql, sql

How to group rows in mysql to be as chunks with a specific size ?

I have a table called `users`

Which has these fields `id` `name`

I want to make a query which group users into chucks with the size of 3 names per row.

Sample table:

```
1 name1
2 name2
3 name4
4 name5
5 name5
6 name6
7 name7
```

result should be

```
name1,name2,name3
name4,name5,name6
name7
```

Usign `GROUP_CONCAT` of course to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6b42/5

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name), 
  (IF(@i = 3 OR @i IS NULL, @i:=1, @i:=@i+1 ))as idx,
  (IF(@gr_idx IS NULL, @gr_idx:=1, IF(@i = 1, @gr_idx:=@gr_idx+1,@gr_idx) )) as gr_idx
FROM users
GROUP BY gr_idx
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM users 
GROUP BY 
floor((id - 1) / 3);
```

Here is an SQL fiddle demonstrating this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3158/2/0

If the IDs are not ascending or not succeeding then this query may be it:

```
SELECT names from (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names,
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM users u, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
GROUP BY floor(@rownum / 3)
) _users ;
```

Fiddle again: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3158/13/0

Comment: that is elegant, but based on `id` value - so it can break if ids are not consistent

Comment: You are right, I actually realised it before reading your comment, so I started writing a new query based on row number that should also be considered by the poster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo arithmetic and conditional aggregation to get three columns:

```
select max(case when mod(id, 3) = 1 then name end),
       max(case when mod(id, 3) = 2 then name end),
       max(case when mod(id, 3) = 0 then name end)
from users u
group by floor((id - 1) / 3);
```

Alternatively, if you only want one column, use `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(name) as names
from users u
group by floor((id - 1) / 3);
```

Both these solutions assume that `id` increases by 1 with no gaps.  If not, there are ways to assign a sequential number using variables.

Comment: that is a cool answer gordon - nb in DB2 / Oracle you can use LISTAGG()

Answer (score 0):

Have similar problem, this is id independent id with windows functions:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) names
FROM users u
     LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_num
      FROM users
     ) AS t ON u.name = t.name
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY FLOOR((row_num-1)/3)
```